# Passing delegate with return type other than void in thread

Tags: c#, delegates, multithreading

I want to pass a delegate with the return type as ArrayList as parameter of thread and want to store the values in an ArrayList as well. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't do that, there is no way to get hold of the return value when the thread has finished. Can you tell us more about what you want done so that we can give you real alternatives?

Comment: Could you explain more?  Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a return value you could try passing in another parameter by reference:

```
private class ThreadArguments
{    
    public ArrayList List1 { get; set; }
    public ArrayList List2 { get; set; }

    public ThreadArguments(ArrayList list1, ref ArrayList list2)
    {
        this.List1 = list1;
        this.List2 = list2;
    }
}

Thread myThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(...));
myThread.Start(args);
```

So the return value is effectively replaced by list2.

Comment: Thanks i solved my prob with different approach instead of returning value through thread.